# MySQL Group_Concat two tables together

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I'm trying to group my data in my tables by all the prices that I have recorded over x days. I'm having trouble with the SQL statement, here is my current statement

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(Price) AS Prices FROM product_prices GROUP BY Product,Day
```

Here is my product_prices table;

```
+---------+--------------+
| Product | Day | Price  |
+---------+--------------+
|    Phone| 1   |  100   |
|  Speaker| 1   |  50    |
|   Phone | 2   |  230   |
|  Speaker| 2   |  80    |
+---------+--------------+
```

Where I want the prices to be group in 1 table by the day like this

```
+---------+----------+
| Product | Prices   |
+---------+----------+
|    Phone| 100, 230 |
|  Speaker| 50, 80   | 
+---------+----------+
```

Comment: You should also show us what output your current query (which is not far off) is giving you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select the prices from lowest to highest, you should use `order by` in your group_concat statement:

```
SELECT Product, 
GROUP_CONCAT(Price ORDER BY Price) AS Prices 
FROM product_prices 
GROUP BY Product
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39b0ad/2)

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove `Day` in the `GROUP BY` clause. Additionally, replace `*`, with `Product`:

```
SELECT
  Product, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(Price) AS Prices 
FROM product_prices 
GROUP BY Product
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3aecd/2/0)</kbd>